# Timed Print Line

Tags: java

How can I print line in x millisecond and print word x millisecond after the previous one?

I'm trying to make a 'Lyric Video' in console. I've tried using

`t.schedule(new TimerTask(){public void run(){System.out.print("");}}, 0, 1000);`

But it prints words EVERY second.

I've tried Google but I can't seem to get the words right.

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
t.schedule(new TimerTask(){public void run(){System.out.print("");}}, 0, 1000);
```

That 1000 gives the number of milliseconds when that timed task is executed.

Or more precisely: **period** *- time in milliseconds between successive task executions.*

So: just change that to your `x` value.

And the **real** answer here: don't just blindly use some API you find somewhere. When in doubt, turn to the javadoc and read what the methods you are calling are doing, like for [schedule()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)). There you would have found that information I quoted above!

Regarding your follow-on questions: again; turn to the javadoc for the *Timer* class. That class has to methods `cancel()` and `purge()` which you can use to prevent future executions.

In other words:

- change 1000 to 5000 to change the delay between print statements
- if you want to stop after a certain iteration, just make sure to call one of the aforementioned methods at some point.

So, when you want to **stop** after 10 seconds, you could do something like:

```
t.schedule(new TimerTask(){public void run(){ t.cancel();}}, 10 
1000);
```

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but I don't get it. Is there a way to print word after 5 seconds then stop printing?

Comment: See my updated answer; but please understand: this is *super basic* stuff. If you don't get things working - make experiments, and keep reading learning. You dont learn programming by asking other people for **all** the details. And: this site is not intended to hold you hand and work with you through all your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `1000` to amount of milliseconds you want. This `1000` means the second you are waiting. Also you could try Thread.sleep() function, if it is a option.

Remember that values passed to that function are in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The value `1000` in your code is actually a milliseconds value.

```
t.schedule(new TimerTask(){public void run(){System.out.print("");}}, 0, 1000);
```

You can change it according to your requirements. Like if you want to wait for 5 seconds, you can change it to `5 * 1000 = 5000`.

```
t.schedule(new TimerTask(){public void run(){System.out.print("");}}, 0, 5000);
```